# Passing VideoView Url to model class in Android

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-videoview

Some Url addresses, tiles and texts are declared in strings.xml file. I want to use mvc architecture.
In the model class the constructor class takes the resource Id of inputs. So the resource id of title, text and url is given. 
In controller class an array of the model class is created. In below code when I want to setText to the TextView it works but when I want to set the Url for the VideoView (***mFilmUrlId.setVideoURI(content)***) doesn't work.
It says:
***setVideoURI cannot be applied to int.***

```
private Content[] mContentBank = new Content[]{
        new Content(R.string.title_1,R.string.url_1,R.string.text_1),
        new Content(R.string.title_2,R.string.url_2,R.string.text_2),
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_training);

    int content;

    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tainingTitle);
    content = mContentBank[mCurrentIndex].getTitle();
    mTitle.setText(content);

    mFilmUrlId = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tainingVideoView);
    content = mContentBank[mCurrentIndex].getFilmUrlId();
    mFilmUrlId.setVideoURI(content);  /// ????????????
```

```
<string name="text_1"> https://as9.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/a_4c13e4fj00iihk43661kg30if959g5j5f35304191771-968u__58a42.mp4
</string>
```

Model class

```
public class Content {
    private int mTitle;
    private int mFilmUrlId;
    private int mTextResId;
    public Content(int title, int filmUrlId, int textResId ){
        mTitle=title;
        mFilmUrlId=filmUrlId;
        mTextResId=textResId;
    }
    //getter &setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setVideoURI() takes Uri as parameter but you are trying to pass R.string.url_1 which is an integer. You need to convert R.string.url_1 to String and then parse as Uri.

```
 content = mContentBank[mCurrentIndex].getFilmUrlId();
 String url = getString(content);
 mFilmUrlId.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
```